# Bootstrap 4 columns not correctly responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I recently started using Bootstrap 4 instead of 3. The first problems start to appear...

When i resize the browser window, the divs are getting on top of eachother. They should break to a new row when it does'nt fit anymore.

Why is the happening and how can i prevent it?

Ill followed the docs, but i can't figure out why its doing this. Bootstrap 3 did'nt had this problem (i know, Bootstrap 4 is using flexboxes)

```css
.first-td-bold tr td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.no-wrap tr td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.no-wrap a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column no-wrap">
          <a class="flex-sm-fill nav-link active" href="#">Alles</a>
          <a class="flex-sm-fill nav-link" href="#">Calculatie</a>
          <a class="flex-sm-fill nav-link" href="#">Opdracht</a>
          <a class="flex-sm-fill nav-link" href="#">Contract</a>
          <a class="flex-sm-fill nav-link" href="#">Meer- minderwerk</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <table class="table table-striped first-td-bold no-wrap">
              <tr>
                <td>Datum toegevoegd</td>
                <td>05-08-2017</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Bestandsnaam</td>
                <td>179358-Wanden.pdf</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Type</td>
                <td>PDF</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Grootte</td>
                <td>8.642,35 KB</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" style="background: #ddd;"></object>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's working: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/84402/

Comment: No, they grey field goes over the table when you resize

Comment: On 1440px wide screen, the 7 of the date is covered with the grey field

Comment: And you forgot my `white-space: nowrap` in your fiddle :). That one in kinda important for my markup.

Comment: are you trying to have it all on the same line?

Comment: Yea there is too little space for the table. What do you expect it there? You can put a div with `table-responsive` to put scroll bars with the table... Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/84412/

Comment: When there is not enought space, i want the grey field to be on a new line.

Comment: @RamonBakker _"When there is not enough space"_ it doesn't work like that. The Bootstrap grid isn't aware of your content, it will break to a new line depending on what responsive classes you use for your columns. Can't you just change `col-md-4` and `col-md-8` to something that works better for your table? Like `col-md-7` and `col-md-5` see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/htekva3d/)

Comment: ok so part of your issue is the nowrap the other part is bootstrap is built for 12 columns, you're trying to force 24 columns into the 12 column system. You start a row at the top which is good, but then you do a 12 column, don't close the row, and start another row inside. If you are trying to do 2 rows, you need to close the first row. If you are trying to do it all on the same line, then you want container-fluid div, row div, and then col-md-2, col-md-6 col-md-6. This still doesn't accomplish your goal because there's not enough room for the table. Middle col needs more room with nowrap

Comment: @Chris Hitchcock Its a nested row. So its 2 - 10 and the 10 divided in 6 - 6. But indeed, even with 2 - 5 - 5 i have the same problem.

Comment: Flexboxes can actually be content aware right? I've seen that before. The goal is; the grey field should fill the remaining space, untill its gets to small (like smaller then the table size)

Comment: @ChrisHitchcock nesting rows is perfectly acceptable

Comment: @RamonBakker Yes they can... define your columns with the `.col` (don't put a number and the row will act more like a flexbox) class then. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/htekva3d/2/). Also read about this more in-depth in the [docs Auto-Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this seems to do what you are looking for. Here's the pen https://codepen.io/chris-hitchcock/pen/BPybej

I did take out the nested row because it seemed negligible with what you are doing, but if you need to put it back, pretty simple. Basically only declared the width of your first one "col-md-2" the rest are col-md to allow the break but have content flow. Also added a little margin to the first column as the middle column was squishing into your navbar.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 pad">
                <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column no-wrap">
                    <a class="flex-sm-fill nav-link active" href="#">Alles</a>
                    <a class="flex-sm-fill nav-link" href="#">Calculatie</a>
                    <a class="flex-sm-fill nav-link" href="#">Opdracht</a>
                    <a class="flex-sm-fill nav-link" href="#">Contract</a>
                    <a class="flex-sm-fill nav-link" href="#">Meer- minderwerk</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md">
                <table class="table table-striped first-td-bold no-wrap">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Datum toegevoegd</td>
                        <td>05-08-2017</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bestandsnaam</td>
                        <td>179358-Wanden.pdf</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Type</td>
                        <td>PDF</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Grootte</td>
                        <td>8.642,35 KB</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md">
                <object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" style="background: #ddd;"></object>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```